# Баг с обновлением контента

Tags: reactjs

Делаю приложение на реакте, суть в том, чтобы когда пользователь вводил сумму и название марки машины, должен появляться список машин, подходящих под сумму и марку. Но после обновления данных в форме, если ввести другую марку или вовсе очистить оба поля, блоки не уходят, как можно это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: <code>введите сюда описание изображения</code>]

```
    enterValue = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const price = document.querySelector('.price'),
            model = document.querySelector('.model');
      if (price.value != false || model.value != false) {
          this.setState({
            userMoney: price.value,
            model: model.value,
          });
      }
     }

renderItems(arr, money, model) {
  return arr.map(item => {
      const { name, src, price, dopname, id } = item;

      if (money >= (+price) && model.toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()) {
          return (
              <div key={id} className="block-cars">
                  <img className='range' src={src} style={{ width: "200px", height: '150px' }} />
                  <div className='descr'>
                      <span>Name: {name}</span>
                      <span>Model: {dopname}</span>
                      <span>Price: {price}</span>
                  </div>
             </div>
            )
        }
    });
}

render() {
    const { posts, userMoney, model } = this.state;

    const items = this.renderItems(posts, userMoney, model);
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className="left">
                <form className='forms' onSubmit={this.enterValue}>
                    <input className="price" />
                    <input className="model" />
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="right">
                {items}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Значения input лучше хранить в стейте и таким образом изменять value.

  const onInputPriceChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setState({
      formPriceValue: e.target.value
    })
  }

 <input className="price" onChange={this.onInputPriceChange} value={this.state.formPriceValue} />'

2. Что бы не делать вот это - `(+price)` можно сделать так - <input className="price" type="number"

3. Метод renderItems использует map, который на каждую итерацию что то должен вернуть.Нужно использовать filter

renderItems(arr, money, model) {
  return arr.filter(item => {
    const { name, src, price, dopname, id } = item;

    if (money >= this.state.formPriceValue && model.toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()) {
      return (
        <div key={id} className="block-cars">
          <img className='range' src={src} style={{ width: "200px", height: '150px' }} />
          <div className='descr'>
            <span>Name: {name}</span>
            <span>Model: {dopname}</span>
            <span>Price: {price}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  });
}
```